# Pooling with least amount of GC on Scala

Tags: android, performance, scala, data-structures

In a game for Android written in Scala, I have plenty of objects that I want to pool. First I tried to have both active (visible) and non active instances in the same pool; this was slow due to filtering that both causes GC and is slow.

So I moved to using two data structures, so when I need to get a free instance, I just take the first from the passive pool and add it to the active pool. I also fast random access to the active pool (when I need to hide an instance). I'm using two ArrayBuffers for this.

So my question is: which data structure would be best for this situation? And how should that (or those) specific data structure(s) be used to add and remove to avoid GC as much as possible and be efficient on Android (memory and cpu constraints)?

Comment: In your code that displays, do you basically iterate across the "active" ArrayBuffer?

Comment: No, that is done by the game engine elsewhere, but I do need to iterate across actives to check for example bullets that have left the playing area. That's done every few frames so it's almost as demanding as the displaying loop would be.

Comment: I was thinking about trying to use a bitmap (with bits set for active), and using a single array buffer. Then you could somewhat rapidly find all the actives (very rapidly find where they aren't, anyway). I can't think of a better way to keep random access and avoid GC. Curious to see if someone has an idea. What sort of ratio for active to inactive do you have? And how many total are there?

Comment: Currently total pool size is around 40, most of the time maybe 10-15 active. And around 20 sets of pools. Collision checking for each etc.

Comment: Oh, if it's that small (10-15/40), is it really that slow to just iterate through all 40 to see which are active? You could even set up a bitmap with just a single Long--but I don't even think it would be worth it, given the logic to find the set bits and set the bits. Seems like an improvement if you're not adding/removing, so you're not hitting GC.

Comment: Well iterating with while could be fast enough but atleast with .filter and .map stuff, even those pools generate way too much garbage when they are run 30-60 times a second on an android device.

Comment: Yeah, try without the filter and map, see if that helps. If it's too slow scanning actives you could try the bitmap idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best data structure is an internal list, where you add

```
var next: MyClass
```

to every class.  The non-active instances then become what's typically called a "free list", while the active ones become a singly-linked list a la `List`.

This way your overhead is exactly one pointer per object (you can't really get any less than that), and there is no allocation or GC at all.  (Unless you want to implement your own by throwing away part or all of the free list if it gets too long.)

You do lose some collections niceness, but you can just make your class be an iterator:

```
def hasNext = (next != null)
```

is all you need given that `var`.  (Well, and `extends Iterator[MyClass]`.)  If your pool sizes are really quite small, sequential scanning will be fast enough.

If your active pool is too large for sequential scanning down a linked list and elements are not often added or deleted, then you should store them in an `ArrayBuffer` (which knows how to remove elements when needed).  Once you remove an item, throw it on the free list.

If your active pool turns over rapidly (i.e. the number of adds/deletes is similar to the number of random accesses), then you need some sort of hierarchical structure.  Scala provides an immutable one that works pretty well in `Vector`, but no mutable one (as of 2.9); Java also doesn't have something that's really suitable.  If you wanted to build your own, a red-black or AVL tree with nodes that keep track of the number of left children is probably the way to go.  (It's then a trivial matter to access by index.)

Comment: Did you miss the bit about *fast random access* to the active pool?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'll mention my idea. The filter and map methods iterate over the entire collection anyway, so you may as well simplify that and just do a naive scan over your collection (to look for active instances). See here: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala

```
def filter(p: A => Boolean): Repr = {
  val b = newBuilder
  for (x <- this)
    if (p(x)) b += x
  b.result
}
```

I ran some tests, using a naive scan of n=31 (so I wouldn't have to keep more than a 32 bit Int bitmap), a filter/foreach scan, and a filter/map scan, and a bitmap scan, and randomly assigning 33% of the set to active. I had a running counter to double check that I wasn't cheating by not looking at the right values or something. By the way, this is not running on Android.

Depending on the number of active values, my loop took more time.

Results:

```
naive scanned a million times in: 197 ms (sanity check: 9000000)
filter/foreach scanned a million times in: 441 ms (sanity check: 9000000)
map scanned a million times in: 816 ms (sanity check: 9000000)
bitmap scanned a million times in: 351 ms (sanity check: 9000000)
```

Code here--feel free to rip it apart or tell me if there's a better way--I'm fairly new to scala so my feelings won't be hurt: https://github.com/wfreeman/ScalaScanPerformance/blob/master/src/main/scala/scanperformance/ScanPerformance.scala